# Is there a way to manage all the subscriptions under an organization in Azure?

Tags: azure, entra-id

Is there any way to manage all the azure subscriptions of an organization as a global administrator or do I need to be added as a co-admin to each individual subscription?

Answer (score 2):

Azure customers with an Enterprise Agreement have access to the [Enterprise Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/enterprise-agreement/) which provides enhanced subscription management capability.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was asked. Especially since we've no idea whether the question is about an Enterprise Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on what you are looking to achieve and how your subscriptions / Active Directory is configured.

Once there is a common administrator across all subscriptions, you can configure a common Active Directory service.

From this point you have two options, you can either be added as a co-administrator individually to each subscription or you can be added as a user in Active Directory and that will work across all subscriptions. (A co-administrator does not have access to Active Directory - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380869/why-as-a-co-administrator-of-a-subscription-am-i-unable-to-edit-the-active-direc))

If you are simply needing to configure Azure Services, i.e. create VMs etc, then an Active Directory account will suffice. If you need to do more than that, then you would need a co-administrator account.

If you can give some indication of what you are hoping to achieve, and what you want to administer we can help you to work out how to achieve it.